# What Cloud Database Providers Are Popular For Simple/Small Apps?

Tags: android, ios, database, amazon-s3, cloud

I'm currently in development of an app that uses a database for storing user-entered data, and has web services as an intermediary between the app and the database.  When I go live, the database and web services needs to be hosted by a provider (can't be local to the device).

I don't have any grand delusions of selling millions of copies of this app, however I'd like to be optimistic and plan for a good case scenario of 10,000 downloads.  For arguments sake, lets say each time it's loaded up, 1 MB of data is transferred during that instance.  I need to make sure that if I charge a few bucks for the app, that it doesn't end up costing me more than that for each user over the course of a couple of years and in turn bankrupt me.

The only real provider I know of is Amazon Web Services/S3.  Are there others that are more popular and/or more economical?  Or is that the most popular/best value route?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your income model. If you have ongoing expenses but only a one-time, up-front fee, that is designed to eventually fail.

Comment: My thoughts exactly @nicerobot but at the same time I'm confused because it seems to be the most common model used by apps.  So, how are others doing it?  I know some sell additional upgrades to unlock features.  But what about those that don't?  Thanks

Comment: Has anyone tried Google Cloud SQL or Windows Azure and know how they pair up to Amazon or MongoLab?

Comment: From what i've seen, they build a product that loses money until they can discover a means to produce revenue or until they go out of business. Many are probably at least partially funded by various in-app marketing and probably VCs that provide resources to help reach a sustainable revenue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [mongolab](http://www.mongolab.com), the free option can easily meet your needs.
p.s. they also have restful api

this list can also help in finding out different options: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hosting+Center

Comment: Interesting @WareNinja   Checked them out...one thing I like about them is that it seems like their pricing is much simpler than the other.  Just goes by storage versus storage + i/o requests + bandwidth + ram/cpu usage, etc.  So simple though that I'm skeptical ;)  I'll have to give them a call.  Are they known to be reputable and fast?

Comment: I've been using MongoLab also in live apps, even shared instances works like a charm

Comment: Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication! :)

Comment: I emailed them and they confirmed their pricing model.  Pretty sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried NuoDB?  They offer an elastically scalable SQL cloud database. Take a look at http://www.nuodb.com/explore/sql-cloud-database-editions/.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the Reserved  Instances of AWS, which require longer term commitment, it works out quite cheap, almost the same as using your own hardware. usage charges are extra, though.

Comment: One thing I don't like about AWS is that their pricing is the most difficult to understand and predict.  But they also seem to be the most popular, so...  They have a free trial so I might use that to get my feet in the water.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a provider with an ongoing freemium plan that meets your performance requirements. This way it might be economical because there won't be an ongoing cost. I know Xeround's cloud MySQL service has a free plan limited to 10MB or so, there is also EnterpriseDB for PostgreSQL which seems to have a free plan (haven't tried it myself). Of course for these types of database services you'll need to host the application itself in the respective cloud (Amazon, RackSpace, etc) and that's not going to be free forever, I believe none of the cloud providers have a perpetual free plan - take the app hosting costs into account.